# How do we integrate cycle renderer with our own app?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

According to following blog post, Blender Cycle path-tracing renderer is allowed (in fact encouraged) to be used in third party application.

http://code.blender.org/index.php/2013/08/cycles-render-engine-released-with-permissive-license/

We really want to integrate Cycle in our application. But I don't know how to start and how will it work. I tried to find but I didn't find any relevant documentation. Is there Scene Description Language like PovRay has ? Or instead does it accept scene info in format like OBJ ? I mean how does it work ?

Comment: See this: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/Standalone "XML API - Cycles standalone has a XML API, which is used for mesh data and shader/settings import. There is no real API documentation at the moment, as the API is subject to change, but you can check the source code to get an idea"

Comment: So you're probably better off using something like LuxRender that actually has a documented [scene file format](http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/Scene_file_format_0.8#Mesh) unless you're willing to integrate and maintain your own cycles source-code integration

Comment: @PeterT, luxrender and cycles are quite different, but wouldn't suggest to pick a raytracer based on its scene description, You really need to weigh up a lot of pros and cons.

Comment: @ideasman42 Sure, there's a lot of factors to compare. But I would say having to maintain a component without a stable interface can be an exclusionary criterion.

Comment: @PeterT - _"API is subject to change"_ just means theres it may change in future, in practice it doesn't mean breaking changes all the time, and even when there are breakages, just stick to a single API version and bundle it, Note that Rhyno3D is integrating Cycles. - http://www.blendernation.com/2014/05/12/developer-meeting-notes-may-11-2014/

Comment: @ideasman42 it doesn't mean things break all the time but it also means that things may break silently for you unless you read every commit message. It means that breaking changes won't necessarily be a big public announcement with a new version number. It means the maintainer isn't committed to a stable API, which has both advantages and disadvantages. I'm not saying he should immediately dismiss it, I'm saying that it's a valid reason to dismiss it.

Comment: @PeterT It makes sense.   We are newly established startup with limited resources and small team. We need to choose the component of our software wisely. While I like Cycle, I wouldn't use it if the API is stable and doesn't have good detailed documentation. 

 Also can you suggest any other raytracer than Luxrender ? How about Yafaray, it has nice XML documentation. Our app is related to interior visualization and is intended to be used in retail environment, so speed is very important . And not all of our customer will have graphic cards in their computers.